# Обязательно ли нужен коммит в основном репозитории при из изменении модуля?

Tags: git, git-submodule

Сейчас читаю статью по работе с модулями в git, из статьи понял что при изменении модуля нужно также делать еще один коммит в основном репозитории чтобы сохранить указатель на последний коммит в модуле.

Это действительно так или я что-то не правильно понял?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Модуль это ссылка на конкретный конкретный **commit**. Если вы хотите, что бы в главный проект ссылался на новую версию, то в нем нужно поменять эту ссылку - сделать новый **commit**. Сослаться на **master** или на другое имя нельзя.

Это сделано для того, что бы можно было восстановить точное состояние репозитория со все подмодулями. То есть сославшись на конкретный  **commit** вы всегда будете уверены, что все файлы/директории во всех модулях именно в том состоянии, что и должны быть.

Answer (score 1):

Это так. И это, пожалуй, самое большое неудобство модулей. С другой стороны это плата то, что неудачный коммит в сабмодуль не сломает вам основной модуль.